# What is the best approach for storing json on AWS for API Rest

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api

I'm designing a REST API in the AWS Cloud. Currently we have some apps publishing data to kinesis in Json format, but now we need expose API REST services to provide that information to some external users. I will use API Gateway to expose my API and Cognito to handle API authentication and security. However, my question and doubts here is about how to storage these json objects in order to recover it faster and efficiently when a service need it.

So, What approach should I use? What databaSe engine should I use? And in the other hand: Should I storage only the json objects? or should I storage it as structured information in a relational model? what is the best approach to manage primary keys for json objects in the tables?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Should I storage only the json objects?" this is  what you can only know.

Comment: Hi @Marcin , my question is about if I should storage the json object I got from kinesis, or I should storage it in a structured way by using  a relational database

Comment: As per the above comment this is entirely solution driven, only you can know that. If you can provide any more details then it'll be easier to work out the solution for you :)